# Can I switch the positions of "called Meituan" and "that offers takeout service" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

An app called Meituan that offers takeout service has launched a "non-contact delivery" service.

Comment: That would make it sound as though the takeout service was called Meituan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but generally you place longer phrases towards the end of a sentence or phrase. So if several arrangements are possible, it is normal to put the longer and "weightier" relative clause after the short participle phrase.

This principle is known as "end weight".